# Tag @see in PhpStorm

Tags: php, intellij-idea, documentation, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have the following code:

```
class A {

    /**
     * Splitter for words
     *
     * @var null|string
     */
    private $splitter = '-';

    /**
     * Desc...
     *
     * @param null|string $splitter   @see $splitter
     */
    function __construct(
        $splitter = null
    ) {
      // implementation
    }

}

$a = new A();
```

When using `CTRL+Q` in `PhpStorm` to see documentation for class constructor I will see:

```
null|string $splitter @see $splitter
```

Am I doing something wrong or should PhpStorm be configured to display description for `$splitter here`. I would expect here to have displayed `Splitter for words` or link to `$splitter` member and not just `@see $splitter`.

As I checked it doesn't matter that those 2 variables have the same name - even if constructor argument name would be `$s` PhpStorm still displays `@see $splitter`.

Comment: **First of all:** when inlined (like you did) the PHPDoc tag should be surrounded by `{}`, like this: `null|string $splitter {@see $splitter}`. **Secondly:** it works in description only (or when alone separate line). It is not parsed as a tag if it is located in `@param` or `@return` description -- not sure if this is a bug or it is should be this way (need to check actual PhpDocumentor behaviour).

Comment: *"I would expect here to have displayed `Splitter for words`"* -- nope. `@see` is just a link to another element -- it should not copy description in any way -- https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#816-see

Comment: @LazyOne Ok, but I mentioned `or link to $splitter member`. PhpStorm does nothing, just displays raw text

Comment: Have you read my "Secondly" in first comment?

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, but I didn't know it could be used in this case. So you tell me I should put it this way: `@param null|string $splitter NEW_LINE {@see $splitter}`? It does seem to work this way - PhpStorm creates link to `$splitter` member

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First of all:** when in-lined (like you did) the PHPDoc tag should be surrounded by `{}`, like this: `@param null|string $splitter {@see $splitter}`

**Secondly:** PhpStorm does NOT parse additional/in-line tags in `@param` or `@return` descriptions -- it only parses it if `@see` is located on separate line or if in-lined in main (method) description section. In other words: in-lining in `@param` description will not work (very ***unfortunately***).

In this regard **PhpStorm behaves just like PhpDocumentor itself** (checked using version 2.6.1).

**Code:**

```
<?php

class PHPDoc_See
{

    /**
     * Splitter for words
     *
     * @var null|string
     */
    private $splitter = '-';

    /**
     * Desc...  {@see $splitter}
     *
     * @param null|string $splitter Bla-Bla {@see $splitter}
     */
    function __construct($splitter = null)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

**PhpDocumentor result:**

[image]

In this regard PhpStorm behaves a bit better -- at least it parses `@see` in main (method) description.

---

The only workable solution (as I see it) is to place `@see` tags on separate lines:

```
/**
 * Some Description
 *
 * @param null|string $splitter Bla-Bla
 * @see $splitter
 */
```

---

**Of course:** you can always **submit Feature Request ticket to the [PhpStorm's Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)** (I would vote for it) .. but considering how PhpDocumentor is behaving in this regard .. I have serious doubts that PhpStorm devs will have it implemented any time soon (they do prefer following the same behaviour as referenced tool).

Comment: I'll accept your answer but there is one more thing. If you put `@see $splitter` in next line this will go `See also` section at the end of documentation of this method. But if you put `{@see $splitter}` in next line PhpStorm will create link to $splitter property right after description: `null|string $splitter Bla-Bla $splitter` (and the last `$splitter` is link here). So in this case there is huge difference if you use `{}` or not to surround. Is it also phpDoc standard? However for me it's quite strange that you have to put it in next line to create link in documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot give you any authoritative answer on such behaviour. I'm surprised that it works like that as technically that second line is still part of the previous line (part of `@param` description). In this regard IDE behaves differently to PhpDocumentor. I may only suggest to submit a ticket asking for better / more consisting behaviour from IDE side -- at least you will get official answer from actual PhpStorm developer.

Comment: I've created issue for phpStorm http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24525 Maybe it will be explained there.

Comment: @StampyCode I do not really see how ticket for `@internal` tag is related to/replaces `@see` tag here...

Comment: @LazyOne ha, sorry, I posted this comment on the wrong SO ticket >.<

Comment: According to PhpDocumentor, inline `@see` are not allowed, however `@link` is allowed: https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.inlinelink.pkg.html (tbh, I'm not sure if this applies to param/return/var/method etc descriptions)